# Why is SSIS saving the last row as NULL when transferring data from Excel to CSV?

Tags: .net, excel, csv, ssis

#### Excel:

Input file contains the data as shown below.

```
Column
------
123456
234567
ADCDEF
```

#### CSV/Text:

Output file contains the data as shown below

```
Column
------
123456
234567
NULL
```

Why does SSIS package write **NULL** value instead of **ABCDEF** in the last row when transferring data from `Excel` to `CSV`?

Comment: Try to check whether you are mapping the last column in `destination`

Comment: what data type is the column in the Excel File Source component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Excel file contains mixed data that is both numerical values and strings, which is causing Excel to read the first few rows and infer the data type of the column as numerical, which is not true in this case. When you create a *Excel Data Source* to read this Excel file, you will notice that the column is defined as number and treats it that way. Hence the string never makes it to the output file.

You need to modify the ConnectionString property of the Excel connection manager to include **`IMEX=1`** to indicate that the data source might contain values of different data types.

`IMEX` stands for **`intermixed`** Read more about it here: [**Connection strings for Excel**](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

Here is an example to illustrate the difference.

I created two identical Excel files as per the data provided in the question.

[image: Excel_1]

[image: Excel_2]

Created an SSIS package with following connection managers.

**Excel_1** had the following connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\temp\ExcelFile_1.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";
```

**Excel_2** had the following connection string. The difference being the additional IMEX=1;. You need to manually add this to the ConnectionString property of the Excel Connection Manager. To view the properties, click on the *Excel Connection Manager* and press **F4**.

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\temp\ExcelFile_2.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES";
```

[image: Connections]

Designed the data flow as shown below to transfer `Excel_1.xls` to `FlatFile_1.csv` and `Excel_2.xls` to `FlatFile_2.csv`

[image: Package]

You can see in the output that the first flat file does not have any value for third row but the second file does. The reason is the first Excel connection manager inferred that the column type is numerical, which is not true. However, the second file treated the

[image: FlatFile_1]

[image: FlatFile_2]

You can right-click on the *Excel data source* and click `Show Advanced Editor...`

[image: Excel data source]

On the Advanced Editor, click `Input and Output Properties`, expand Excel Source Output and then expand `External Columns`. Click `Column`.

You will notice that the data type of the column on first Excel data source is set to **`double-precision float [DT_R8]`** on the first Excel connection manager `Excel_1`

[image: Excel_1 Advanced]

You will notice that the data type of the column on second Excel data source is set to **`Unicode string [DT_WSTR]`** on the first Excel connection manager `Excel_2`

[image: Excel_2 Advanced]

Hope that helps.